# How to search in AngularJS after typing 4 chars in input

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angularjs

I have a `MySQL` database and I search in it using `AngularJS`. How to search only if I print 4 or more chars in this input?

HTML code:

```
<div class="search">
  <form action="" method="post" class="searchform" >
    <input type="search" name="" placeholder="Search" class="inputsearchform" ng-model="search"/>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submitsearchform" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="songlist" >
  <table id="songlistTableR" ng-controller='main_control'>   
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Link</th></tr>    
    <tr class="rowR" ng-repeat="data in loaded | filter:{song_name: search}">
      <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>{{data.song_name}}</td>
      <td><a href="{{data.link}}" target='_blank'>Youtube</a></td>     
    </tr>
  </table>      
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('test_table', []);
app.controller('main_control',function($scope, $http){
    load();
    function load(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
            $scope.loaded=data; 
        });
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but the solution is to just add the ng-minlength attribute. Used as this:

```
<input type="search" name="" placeholder="Search" class="inputsearchform" ng-model="search" ng-minlength="4"/>
```

That should accomplish what you are wanting.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I have another problem, all results appear if I change input. How make angular not to show results before I type 4 chars?

Comment: Do you mean you want to not show the results table at all until there are >4 chars in the input? You can do that with ng-hide. `ng-hide="search.length <4"` Or something similar to that on your table or div that has the results.